# error loading images (_netwok_image_io.dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting this error when scrolling down list of images online the error occurs if the list is big.

```
catch (e) {
      // Depending on where the exception was thrown, the image cache may not
      // have had a chance to track the key in the cache at all.
      // Schedule a microtask to give the cache a chance to add the key.
      scheduleMicrotask(() {
        PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict(key);
      });
      rethrow;
    } finally {
      chunkEvents.close();
    }
  }
```

i dont know how do i fix it and here is my code

```
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    matches[0].leaguelogo,
                    width: 30.h,
                    height: 30.h,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10.h),
                  Text(
                    leagueName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.sp,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```